# IndexError: list index out of range ,I do not use out list index

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna parse excel and put data in the model(User). I wrote in views.py

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

cells = [
    ('user_id', 0, 5),
    ('name', 3, 1),
    ('nationality', 3, 2),
    ('domitory', 3, 3),
    ('group', 3, 4)]

user1 = {key:sheet.cell_value(rowy, colx) for key, rowy, colx in cells}

print(user1)
```

Excel is
[image: excel]

In this case,domitory is empty.I run this code,so error happens

```
IndexError: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py", line 112, in <module>
    user1 = {key:sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx) for key, rowy, colx in cells}
  File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py", line 112, in <dictcomp>
    user1 = {key:sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx) for key, rowy, colx in cells}
  File "/Users/XXX/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 415, in cell_value
    return self._cell_values[rowx][colx]
```

I cannot understand why this error happens because I did not write codes was  ‎accessed to out of index list.But how can I fix this?What should I write it?

I wrote code by seeing answer,but some errors happen like
[image]

Comment: You could try catching that exception and writing 0 or N/A instead of breaking out http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/exception-handling-in-python

Comment: I cannot understand ur comments.If I write ur comments in my code,what should i write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if a cell is blank or empty before trying to get it's value. I've never used xlrd so I have no idea if that's the issue:

```
user1 = {key:sheet.cell_value(rowy, colx) if sheet.cell_type(rowy, colx) not in (xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY, xlrd.XL_CELL_BLANK) else key:None for key, rowy, colx in cells}
```

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur codes,but some errors happens.I updated my question,if u know something please help me.

Comment: And I wanna embet null in empty cell,do u intend to write codes if cell has empty,rows are skipped?

Comment: What errors did you get? I see your IDE is underlining some words but those aren't errors. The intention is to check if a cell is empty or blank: if yes, return `key:None`. If not, return `key:cell_value(x,y)`. Ultimately it's up to you to decide what you want to do with empty / blank cells.

Comment: It was said unsolved reference 'key' & 'rowy' & 'colx',and Statement expected was said in None , and  Colon is expected was said in last }. I wanna put null or None in empty cell.